# How to separate values from one column into two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, pivot

I have the below data-set where a user has more than 1 Contact No associated to their Name.  The below is just a small sample of my data-set.

```
Name     Contact No   
-------  ----------
Deepika  75865558 
Deepika  207586558
Rnveer   746655558
Rnveer   946655558
vaibhav  2356841
vaibhav  6655558
```

I want to split the Contact No into their own columns to consolidate the information as shown below.

```
Name     Con 1      Con 2
-------  ---------  ---------
Deepika  75865558   207586558
Rnveer   746655558  946655558
vaibhav  2356841    6655558
```

How can I get data that is only located in a single table, and in the same column to output in 2 columns?  See the above example.

Comment: What if there are 3 rows with `Name = 'Deepika'`? What if there are 4 or 400? What is there is only 1?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which does what you want and will get you started with using PIVOT. Sorry it is a bit rushed, but hopefully it will get you started and show you how it can be done fairly easily.

There will be limitations and I would fully advise researching and playing with the pivot functions because they are really powerful.

```
-- Some sample data to work with
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
    ,contactnumber BIGINT
    )

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES (
    'Deepika'
    ,75865558
    )
    ,(
    'Deepika'
    ,5181568
    )
    ,(
    'Deepika'
    ,56954121
    )
    ,(
    'Rnveer'
    ,4561896
    )
    ,(
    'Rnveer'
    ,48640655
    )
    ,(
    'vaibhav'
    ,48640655
    );

--The pivot
WITH PivotData
AS (
    SELECT NAME --The row group
        ,'Contact ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY contactnumber ASC
                ) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS TheRow --The value that will form columns
        ,contactnumber
    FROM @SampleData
    )
SELECT *
FROM PivotData
PIVOT(AVG(contactnumber) FOR TheRow IN (
            [Contact 1]
            ,[Contact 2]
            ,[Contact 3]
            ,[Contact 4]
            )) AS ThePivot1
```

Answer (score 1):

if is is just two then

```
select name
     , min(Contact No) as [cont 1]
     , max(Contact No) as [cont 2]  
from table 
group by name
```